# AspectJ: What does this code mean?

Tags: java, syntax, aop, concurrentmodification

I have just started aspect-oriented programming and have come across an example that checks for concurrent modification in the collection. But I am having problems understanding the meaning of the code:-

```java
public aspect FailSafeIter {
    Map<Iterator,Collection> iterToColl = new HashMap<Iterator,Collection>();

    // Create interator
    after(Collection c) returning (Iterator i):
        call(* Collection.iterator()) && target(c)
    {
        iterToColl.put(i,c); 
    }

    // Update collection
    after(Collection c) returning:
        (call(* Collection.add(..)) || call(* Collection.remove(..)) ) && target(c)
    {
        iterToColl.values().remove(c);
    }

    // Iterate over collection
    before(Iterator i):
        call(* Iterator.*()) && target(i)
    {
        if(!iterToColl.containsKey(i))
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();  
    }
}
```

Can anybody explain what do the above lines mean and how does it detect concurrent modification exception?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html

Comment: @MuratK. How does that explain the code?

Comment: How does the link help?? The problem that I am facing is with the syntax and the logic behind it??

Comment: The syntax is AspectJ or similar, covering that is too broad. The logic can be traced through pretty easy, or use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I have just fixed your code formatting and changed the comments to be a little bit more descriptive so as to enable you to see what is happening:

- The first pointcut captures calls to `Collection.iterator()`, i.e. the advice method records all newly created iterators along with their corresponding collections in an internal key-value map `iterToColl`. This is the first step of internal bookkeeping done by the aspect.
- The second pointcut captures calls to `Collection.add(..)` or `Collection.remove(..)`, i.e. calls to methods modifying a collection (which is a caveat and should not be done while iterating over it). If it finds a call, the advice will remove all key-value pairs relating to this collection from the internal map.
- The third pointcut is a bit fuzzy because it captures calls to all iterator methods, e.g. `Iterator.next()` (which is probably the intention), but also to harmless methods like `Iterator.hasNext()` (which is probably unwanted here). If such a call is intercepted, the advice checks if the iterator in question is found in the internal map. If it is found, everything is okay and the advice does nothing. Otherwise it throws a `ConcurrentModificationException` because it assumes that the collection using the iterator has been modified during an ongoing iteration. In the latter case the collection would have been removed from the map earlier in the second advice described above.

All in all this aspect is pretty cryptic and will only work under very specific circumstances (if at all due to the imprecise pointcuts). There are plenty of options for it to break, IMO. But it is a funny idea anyway and might work for straightforward, simple cases. I have not tested it, though. I merely used the AspectJ parser in my brain to figure it out.

I hope the explanation suffices.